# Azure Function App - PHP & XML Output

Tags: php, xml, azure, azure-functions

In a very similar issue described in this post https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/942 - When pushing an output with XML content, Azure seems to wrap the content in serialized tags. Effectively nesting the XML in its own.

There appears to be a way to set the headers and provide additional context to the output in NodeJS. You can define the value as XML which in turn ensures that the content isn't wrapped.

Does anyone have a similar solution for PHP? I've tried defining Headers/Content Type with no success.

Thanks in advance!

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mamaso said, this is a known issue: [php azure function can't set content type #1554](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1554).

> This is a known issue - the `isRaw` flag only applies to node at present. It can only be set in script languages if you serialize to a json string, which turns any bytes into base64 strings (defeating the purpose of isRaw). I'll have a think on how to indicate a raw response from script languages.
>
> Unfortunately there is not a workaround, unless if you can use C#, F#, or node.